# Changing the views default path on Codeigniter 3.0 versions

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

On codeigniter 3 when loading a view, the default path is application / views /

I would like to be able to change the default path to application / views / template /

I use to be able to change the default view path on MY_Loader.php `$this->_ci_view_path = APPPATH .'views/template/';` as shown below. Currenly it only suited for CI2 does not seem to work on CI3

**Question** On codeigniter 3.0 versions what is the best method of changing the default view path, can it be done similar to my MY_Loader from CI2 to CI3.

```
<?php

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

   function __construct() {
      // Change this property to match your new path

      $this->_ci_view_path = APPPATH .'views/template/';
      $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
      $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      $this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);
      log_message('debug', "Loader Class Initialized");
   }
}
```

Comment: can you clear bit more about question. I didn't understand your question exactly

Comment: @Abdulla have updated it.

Comment: is V3 is HMVC ?? or normal???

Comment: @Abdulla Problem Solved as in my answer . HMVC is third party which I am not using, atm

Comment: Change like this `$this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH.'views/template/' => TRUE);`

Comment: ah exactly i mean this. You posted it

Comment: @Abdulla Thanks for your time.

Comment: missed +50. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solved

The problem was here

**CI2 Versions**

```
$this->_ci_view_path = APPPATH .'views/somefoldername/';
```

**Now CI3 Versions**

```
$this->_ci_view_paths = array(
    APPPATH . 'views/somefoldername/' => TRUE
);
```

How to change the default view path in Codeigniter 3

> application > core > MY_Loader.php

```
<?php

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();

        $this->_ci_view_paths = array(
            APPPATH . 'views/somefoldername/' => TRUE
        );

        $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);

        $this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);

        $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);

        log_message('debug', "Loader Class Initialized");

    }
}
```

## Update for HMVC & Codeigniter 3

This symbol * in glob on code below meaning module name.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();

        // Default
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array(
            APPPATH . 'views/' => TRUE
        );

        // Modules
        $module_view_paths = glob(APPPATH . 'modules/*/views/template/', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        foreach ($module_view_paths as $module_view_path) {
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array(
                $module_view_path => TRUE,
            );
        }

        $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);

        $this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);

        $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);

        log_message('debug', "Loader Class Initialized");

    }
}
```

This allows you to do this for HMVC loading of views

```
$this->load->view('folder_name/view_name');
```

Instead of

```
$this->load->view('template/folder_name/view_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check `index.php` file again, you'll see that every single line is well explained. For this particular line in subject is written:

> If you do move this, use the full server path to this folder.

Answer (score 2):

Change this to

```
$this->_ci_view_path = APPPATH .'views/template/'; # Works on CI 3.0-
```

this

```
$this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH.'views/template/' => TRUE); # Works on CI 3.0+
```

[Posting My Comment as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340474/changing-the-views-default-path-on-codeigniter-3-0-versions#comment54567577_33340474)

Answer (score 1):

Actually It's not  the answer to your Question But  it will act as a alternate solution.

Override `view()` method or create new function by extending `CI_Loader`  to achive desired result

```
public function my_view($file,$data)
{
    $this->view("template/$file",$data);
}
```